# How to perform actions on a variable in a foreach while being able to use it afterwards

Tags: rust

I have the following example code (including use statements too so there's some context on types):

```rust
use actix_web::{HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Responder};
use awc::ClientRequest;

pub async fn proxy(req: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
    let response = construct_request(req).send().await;

    let body = response.unwrap().body().await.expect("");

    HttpResponse::Ok().body(body)
}

fn construct_request(req: HttpRequest) -> ClientRequest {
    let client = awc::Client::default();

    let mut new_req = client.get("url");

    req.headers().iter().for_each(|headerPair| {
        new_req.append_header((headerPair.0, headerPair.1));
    });
        
    new_req.content_type("application/json")
}
```

Currently, the compiler complains that I'm using the `new_req` value after it being moved in the foreach loop to copy the headers over, which is fair enough, that is what's happening.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `new_req`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
   --> src/routes/proxy.rs:18:9
    |
15  |       let mut new_req = client.get("http://localhost:8001/ping");
    |           ----------- captured outer variable
16  |
17  |       req.headers().iter().for_each(|headerPair| {
    |  ___________________________________-
18  | |         new_req.append_header((headerPair.0, headerPair.1));
    | |         ^^^^^^^ ------------------------------------------- `new_req` moved due to this method call
    | |         |
    | |         move occurs because `new_req` has type `ClientRequest`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
19  | |     });
    | |_____- captured by this `FnMut` closure
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `new_req`
   --> /Users/{sanitized}/awc-3.0.1/src/request.rs:186:30
    |
186 |     pub fn append_header(mut self, header: impl TryIntoHeaderPair) -> Self {
    |                              ^^^^

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src/routes/proxy.rs:15:9
   |
15 |     let mut new_req = client.get("http://localhost:8001/ping");
   |         ----^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         help: remove this `mut`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `new_req`
  --> src/routes/proxy.rs:21:5
   |
15 |     let mut new_req = client.get("http://localhost:8001/ping");
   |         ----------- move occurs because `new_req` has type `ClientRequest`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
16 |
17 |     req.headers().iter().for_each(|headerPair| {
   |                                   ------------ value moved into closure here
18 |         new_req.append_header((headerPair.0, headerPair.1));
   |         ------- variable moved due to use in closure
...
21 |     new_req.append_header(("custom", req.headers().get("custom").unwrap()))
   |     ^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

What I can't find out is how I can work around this so that I can continue to use `new_req` after the foreach loop - is this possible? I've tried doing some googling around preventing this movement but I haven't managed to find anything (I'm assuming this is a very simple resolution that I just don't have the right words to discover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find by looking at the signature of [`.append_header()`](https://docs.rs/awc/latest/awc/struct.ClientRequest.html#method.append_header) and other methods that they will consume `self` and return `Self`. This is a type of builder-pattern that is designed to work like this:

```
let new_req = client.get("url")
    .append_header(...)
    .append_header(...)
    .append_header(...)
    .content_type("application/json");
```

or like this:

```
let mut new_req = client.get("url");
new_req = new_req.append_header(...);
new_req = new_req.append_header(...);
new_req = new_req.append_header(...);
new_req = new_req.content_type("application/json");
```

Unfortunately, constant ownership transfers like this don't play well with closures if you want to keep the value afterwards. You're probably better suited just using a `for`-loop instead:

```
for header_pair in req.headers() {
    new_req = new_req.append_header(header_pair);
}
```

Or if you insist on using `.for_each()`, you can modify the request in-place by using [`.headers_mut()`](https://docs.rs/awc/latest/awc/struct.ClientRequest.html#method.headers_mut):

```
req.headers().iter().for_each(|header_pair| {
    new_req.headers_mut().insert(header_pair.0.clone(), header_pair.1.clone());
});
```

---

If you're in the uncomfortable situation where you *must* take and reassign ownership and it *must* be while captured in a closure, you'll have to employ a trick using `Option`:

```
// put it in an option
let mut new_req_opt = Some(new_req);

req.headers().iter().for_each(|header_pair| {
    // take it out of the option
    let mut new_req = new_req_opt.take().unwrap();

    // do your thing
    new_req = new_req.append_header(header_pair);

    // put it back into the option
    new_req_opt = Some(new_req);
});

// take it out again at the end
let new_req = new_req_opt.unwrap();
```

Comment: Fortunately just the standard for loop works for me, though I'll have to bear those other two routes in mind, particularly the latter - thanks for the help! Still getting used to the ownership model